# No password set. django save user without form

Tags: python, django, rest

Sorry for my english. Now i learning django rest, and i not clearly understand how save user. For example: i want you send json to server and server save new user

`{"username": "bob", "password":"123321"}`

in **views** i writed method for save user

```
@csrf_exempt
def request_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'message' : 'incorect json format'}, safe=False)

        serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

my serializers

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
```

but in admin i see: **No password set.**. Why my user save without password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no password in fields:

```
       fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
```

For correct password set you need rewrite create method

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added it field in my serializers, but now i have **Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.**

Comment: i add info to the answer